# mySQL update a value

Tags: mysql

Modified some stuff from my pic so you guys can understand it
I have this database. I am trying to update a value from a table based on another value from an another table.

[image]

I want to update the `SUM` from `salary` like this :

```
( sum  = presence * 5 )
```

This is what I've been trying to use ( unsuccessful )

```
update table salary
      set suma.salary = users.presence * 5 
      FROM salary INNER JOIN users1 INNER JOIN presence on id_salary = id_presence
```

I am not sure what to do, I'd appreciate some help, Thanks

Comment: You have table salary, but in query you write salariu. Why? Also never forget to add `WHERE` clause in your query or all rows would be updated. Also, I don't see field `pontaj` in `users1` table. Edit your answer , please.

Comment: SET comes after. And you have no join condition on users. Basically, there's so much wrong that I think you need to go back to the books/manuals/tutorials first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL to UPDATE tables with a join you use this syntax:

```
UPDATE table1, table2
   SET table1.column = some expression
WHERE table1.column = table2.column
```

That said, even with the updated picture, in your SQL you are mentioning columns that I cannot understand in which table are to be found. You also have an inner join between salariu and users1, with no join condition. Could you please clean up the question and make everything clear?

Assuming you are making the updates to the db structure you were talking about, then you can start working on this one maybe:

```
UPDATE salary, presence
  SET salary.sum = SUM(presence.hours) * 5
WHERE presence.id = salary.id
AND   <some filter on the month that depends on salary.date>
```

Another way, but I'm not sure it is supported in all RDBMS, would be something like this:

```
UPDATE salary
  SET sum = (
     SELECT SUM(presence.hours) * 5
     FROM user, presence
     WHERE presence.id = salary.id
     AND   <some filter on the month that depends on salary.date>
  )
```

Comment: I still don't understand the structure. It would seem you have many user records to one presence record... is that correct? I would expect the presence table to have the user id and so many presences to one user.

Comment: I am trying to make it somewhat unique. What do I mean by that is to have the presence / id , I see what you're telling me, there's some repetition. I think I 'll have to change the presence table

Comment: Wait, I do have an ID presence for each user, making it unique for each of them, isn't it ?

Comment: You said presence contains the hours worked, right? I'd expect it to have a structure like (user_id, date???, hours_worked) or something equivalent... and I would not expect to have a presence_id in the users table (if a user has many presences, then no single presence_id has any right to reside in the users table).

Comment: As a further suggestion... usually each table has its own id column... plus maybe one or more "<something>_id" columns to reference other (master) tables. So in salary, "id" would be the salary id, while the user id would be called "user_id". In departments the "dep_id" should just be "id". That would make the structure more intuitive to other developers here... but of course I understand you could not be in a position to change this.

Comment: I can change that, I'll make a new presence table based on your advices, and return in a few moments with a new DB

Comment: Another problem... if you have many salaries per user, which one are you going to update? All of them? With the same total of hours*5 for each user?

Comment: Well, kinda, I was thinking about updating them all since their schedule will have around (eX) 8h/ day. And if I add bonus/penalties tables that will awards employees with more h made than the normal limit ( let's say 45h/week) then I will update their salaries accordingly.

Comment: There is something missing I think. The salary is daily? Then you should have a date column in the presence, right? How else can you know what presences to sum up?

Comment: Actually the salary is monthly  sorry, my bad. The salary will me monthly so , in the salary table I'll calculate directly the number of hours an employee has.

Comment: Ok. Slowly, but we are getting somewhere. Now... how do you suppose you are going to find the hours the employee worked in a certain month? Wouldn't you need to know **when** he worked and not just how many hours? That's why I'd expect a date column in the presence table.

Comment: So you thought about the table like this : 
Id-presence / id-user(external  key) /nr.hours / date

So after the 30 days I can do a count and see how much did he work, and from there to set up his salary.

Comment: Yes... (id, user, id, date, hours_worked). And no presence_id in the users table.

Comment: Ok, I am making the proper adjustments and try to update query, I'll be back in like 10 minutes

Comment: This is how does the DB look like
Sorry for the late response but i still have trouble calculating this stuff.

UPDATE salary
  SET salary.sum = (5 * sum(presence.hours))
  FROM salary  WHERE presence.id_presence = salary.id_salary

not sure if I should use WHERE of INNER join....

Comment: You cannot directly join salary and presence... you have to go through the user table

Comment: this is what I did but without any success. 
it also checks out the number of hours made and judging by that the salary will be modified

UPDATE salary
   SET sum.salary = IF(sum(presence.hours) < 30 OR sum(presence.hours) > 30 ,salary.sum = ((5 * sum(presence.hours) - 25/100 * sum(presence.hours)) ,salary.sum = ((5 * sum(presence.hours) + 25/100 * sum(presence.hours)))
FROM salary INNER JOIN users1 on salary.id_salary  = users1.id

Comment: Take a look over the link, you'll see the code much more clearer

Comment: You have to join all 3 tables... now you are joining just salary and users1, but then you reference presence.hours, which certainly cannot be resolved. Another thing... that IF... that doesn't look good. Take it away for now and concentrate on the simpler problem of SUM(presence.hours) * 5

Comment: The syntax is still wrong... there is no FROM... and each JOIN has to have its own ON clause. Could you please try the one I update in my answer?

Comment: I've seen that you have updated the thread, I don't have anymore users1.presence_id, I've deleted it based on your suggestions 
http://prntscr.com/39cruc

Comment: Ok, sorry... I've updated it again. For now try without the condition on the date. That one won't be easy

Comment: You are using the wrong join fields... use salary.id=presence.id

Comment: I've tried with several join fields, it's still not working
http://pastebin.com/ihJMpnU2

Comment: The join fields are right this time, it seems. Try with the subselect... that would be the last UPDATE statement posted in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me, I'm new to this DB stuff, I'm just going to implement this into my VB project. Thanks again